# Python post request check checkbox and submit

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, request

I want to tick a checkbox and then submit the form via Python. Don't know how to work it out.
HTML Parts:

Checkbox:

```
 <input  type="checkbox" value="17213463" class="vehicle_checkbox" id="vehicle_checkbox_17213463" name="vehicle_ids[]"

              fms="2"
              id="vehicle_checkbox_17213463"
              class="vehicle_checkbox"
              building_id="4537773"
              custom_="1"
              tractive_random="0"
              ignore_aao="0"
              vehicle_type_ignore_default_aao="0"
              tractive_vehicle_id="0"
              tractive_building_random="0"
              trailer_vehicle_id="0"
              fire="1"
              wasser_amount="2000"
              lf_only="1"
              possible_tractive="[]"

          >
```

Submit:

```
          <input class="btn btn-success  " id="alert_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Alarmieren" />
```

What i tried so far:

```
serviceurl = 'https://www.leitstellenspiel.de/missions/1502249226'
payload = {"17213463":"checked"}
r = s.post(serviceurl, data=payload,headers=headers)
print("Status code: ", r.status_code)
print("Printing Entire Post Request")
print(r.content)
```

But i get an 404 Error, though i can reach the website via s.get(thisURL). I googled for an eternity but did not find the right code. May someone help`?

Comment: Did you take a look at Python Web Frameworks like Flask?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar Flask is for hosting a server service, I don't think that's what OP needs

Comment: Yeah, never mind.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Can you show what packages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()

serviceurl = 'https://www.leitstellenspiel.de/missions/1502249226'

payload = {"user_remember_me":"1"}

r = s.get(serviceurl, data=payload)

print("Status code: ", r.status_code)

print("Printing Entire Post Request")

print(r.content)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30212451)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).